# SciPy curve_fit runtime error, stopping iteration

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` in an iterative way.

My problem is that when ever it is unable to fit the parameters the whole program (and thus the iteration) stops, this is the error it gives:

`RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.`

I understand that why it has been unable to fit. My problem is that is there any way I can write the program in Python 3.2.2 that will ignore such occurrences and just continue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use standard Python exception handling to trap the error raised by `curve_fit` in cases where the optimization fails to find a solution. So something like:

```
try:
    popt,pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None)

except RuntimeError:
    print("Error - curve_fit failed")
```

That construct will let you catch and handle the error condition raised by `curve_fit` without having your program abort.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to Python and this error was really bothering me. I read the manual on the try-except error handling procedure and understood it. Thanks again...

Comment: So one quick word to wrap this up. Does an error like this (even when is raised to, say, `maxfev=2000`) mean that the fit is not possible, e.g., the curve we are trying to fit is not a good fit, or maybe not a fit at all? Ultimately, if you are testing a number of laws, is this error telling us that we should discard the function for which the error was raised?